# How to call Javascript event function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to call a Javascript event from another Javascript function by obtaining this event via getter?

Some example code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyDownHandler(elem, e)
    {
       var keyId = e.keyCode;
       if(keyId === 13)
       {
          var clickMethod = elem.onclick;
          //now call the clickHandler method.
       }
    }
    </script>
    
    
    <input type="text" onkeydown="keyDownHandler(this, event)"
           onclick="clickHandler(this)" />
```

I want to invoke the method defined in `onclick` attribute of the input field.

Comment: see below example for solution

Comment: Did you *try* invoking it? What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim S. said, you can directly call handler, however if you really want to call the event, you can use Jquery 'trigger'.

```
$(elem).trigger('click')
```

if elem is not jquery object.

Edit: jquery is not required. The code should work by just adding the parenthesis in onclick call.

```
function keyDownHandler(elem, e) {
            var keyId = e.keyCode;
            if (keyId === 13) {
                elem.onclick();
            }
        }
```

clickHandler must be defined.

Comment: OP does not seem to use jQuery, so he would have to included it, and `elm` would have to be a jQuery object.

Comment: no, its the element which is passed in the function 'elem' or you can get it using $("#elementId") or document.getElementById("elementId")

Comment: Of course... but it still has to be a jQuery object, not the DOM element. In the OP's code it's a DOM element.

Comment: That moment when one does not knows the difference between a DOM and  an jQuery object.

Comment: yes, thats correct, if he can use Jquery its just the matter of wrapping it in $ e.g. $(elem).trigger('click')

Comment: This answer is correct : ) I figured it out by my own testing something, then I came here to answer my own question, but voilla you got it before me : )) Grats

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend that.

You need to abstract the shared login out of the `onclick` handler as a separate method and then call the method from both the event handlers.

```
function sharedloginc(some arguments...) {
    //do something
}

function keyDownHandler(el, e) {
    //do something
    sharedloginc(....)   
}

function clickHandler(el, e){
    sharedloginc(....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyDownHandler(elem, e)
{
    var keyId = e.keyCode;

    if(keyId === 13)
    {
        // call function, normally
        clickHandler(elem, null);
    }
}
</script>
```

I have set the `event` argument `null`, because, well, you can't generate a (correct!) event object.

---

Okay after some playing around I have managed to make this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function keydown_handler(el, e) {
    var click, code = e.keyCode;

    if(code === 13) {
        var handler = el.onclick;

        if(typeof handler === 'function') {
            handler.apply(this, el, null);
        }
    }
}

function click_handler(el, e) {
    alert('clicked!');
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="keydown_handler(this, event);" onclick="click_handler(this, event);" />
```

It seems to work, but I can't verify it works in all browsers at this point.

Comment: well thanks but i want the original function to be called. That one defined in the onlick attribute

Answer (score 0):

This example will solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 function keyDownHandler(elem, e)
                   {
                       var keyId = e.keyCode;
                       if(keyId == 13)
                       {
                         // var clickMethod = elem.onclick;
                          clickHandler(elem, e);
                        }
                   }
                  function clickHandler(elem, e)
                  {
                    alert("clickHandler");
                  }
           </script>
       <input type="text" onkeydown="keyDownHandler(this, event)" onclick="clickHandler(this, event)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in which browser you are running your page

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one-liner within keydown/keyup event attributes. These are the possible options.

for executing the onclick/click event on the same element.

```
((e)=>{if(e.keycode===13) click():})(event)
```

or

```
((e)=>{if(e.keycode===13) this.click()})(event)
```

for executing the onclick/click event by elementID.

```
((e)=>{if(e.keycode===13) elementID.click()})(event)
```